# Why "return" on a promise-based test with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This is a Jest test example :

```js
test("Asynchronous code", () => {
    return Promise.resolve("data").then(res => {
        expect(res).toBe("data");
    });
});
```

[Docs for Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) indicate that we have to `return` a Promise in a test, because without `return`:

> Your test will complete before the promise returned [...] and then() has a chance to execute the callback.

So if I don't `return`, `expect(res).toBe("data")` will never be executed.

But I tested, and it worked the same with or without `return` (with `.resolves` and `.rejects` as well).

To be sure, I write a test without `return` supposed to failed :

```js
test("Asynchronous code", () => {
    Promise.resolve("data").then(res => {
        expect(res).toBe("a failure");
    });
});
```

- If `expect(res).toBe("data")` is never executed, the test will pass: `return` is required.
- If the assertion is well tested, the test failed: what do we need `return` for?

```
 FAIL  Cours-Jest/--test--/test.js
  ● Asynchronous code

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "a failure"
    Received: "data"
```

So the assertion is correctly executed. Why do we have to `return`? What am I missing?

Comment: Return is needed so that _Jest_ gets the chance to handle the promise. Without return the assertion failure is an unhandled promise rejection, which in newer versions of Node means the test suite _crashes_, rather than the test failing.

Comment: does jest not support async/await like this:
`test("Asynchronous code", async () => {
    const res = Promise.resolve("data");
    expect(res).toBe("data");
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:

> Return a promise from your test, and Jest will wait for that promise to resolve. If the promise is rejected, the test will fail.

So when you do something asynchronously and don't return the promise, two things can go wrong:

1. When your promise actually does something asynchronously that takes longer than the test timeout ... your `.then()` will not fire at all. There may even be no timeout, as your test  returns immediately.
2. When your promise is rejected, the error is ignored.

A better way to test promises:

```
test("Asynchronous code", async () => {
    const res = await Promise.resolve("data");
    expect(res).toBe("data");
});
```

Comment: That's make sense ! Thanks HEIIRZA ^^